# Numpy: values in array wont change

Tags: arrays, numpy, assign

The below code is supposed to calculate some values and place them in incremental places in the numpy.zeros() array. The calculations all perform correctly but the array stays as just zeros. I could be missing something obvious so apologies if I am.

```
n = 256
lam = l

a = numpy.zeros([(len(z[0]) * len(z[:,0]) + n + 1), (n + len(z[0]))])
b = numpy.zeros([numpy.size(a, 0), 1])

#data fitting equations
k = 0
for i in range(len(z[0])):
    for j in range(len(z[:,0])-1):
        wij = smoother(z[j][i] + lam)
        a[k][(z[j][i]+lam)] = float(wij)
        print a[k][(z[j][i]+lam)]
        a[k][n+j] = float(-wij)

        b[k][0] = float(-wij * B[j])
        k = k + 1
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Could you post a full working example?  It's hard to debug code if what we're given doesn't run.

Comment: Can't test it right now, bur replace all your indexing like `a[i][j]` with `a[i, j]` and I think you'll solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Jaime that seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer supplied by Jaime works fine. Use

```
a[1, 2]
```

rather than

```
a[1][2]
```